# Shell Script while loop for converting a file into variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix

So I have a snippet of the excel forms, and I am trying to use bash script to convert them into a format we want.
The file looks like this:
Group1  Member1
      **************  Member2
************** Member123
Group2   Member183
**********Member1023

So on and so forth....
What the file means, is that it's essentially a form. Where it tells you that Group 1 has the member of "Member1" "Member2""Member123". THe "******"means it's a blank field. I am trying to use a while loop to read all the group names (column1) into variable $Groupname and all the members (column2) into variable $Groupmember, and then use awk to print something like this:
Group 1 Member1
Group 1 Member2
Group 1 Member123
So how can I do that?

Comment: "blank field" means, filled with spaces, or literally filled with asterisks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this:

**input.txt**

> Group1 Member
>  
>   *********  Member2
>  *********  Member123
>  Group2
>   Member183
>  *********  Member1023

Then in a bash script, you could keep track of the most recent group used:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENTGROUP=""

while read -r group member
do
        if [[ ${group:0:1} != "*" ]]; then
                CURRENTGROUP=$group
        fi

        echo "$CURRENTGROUP $member"

done < "input.txt"
```

Which produces the following output:

> Group1 Member
>  
>   Group1 Member2
>  
>   Group1 Member123
>   Group2 Member183
>  
>   Group2 Member1023